# Android - Issues with Handling multiple CheckBoxes

Tags: java, android, checkbox

In my application I have 5 CheckBoxes. In the onclick-method I have following Code:

```
bt_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
cb_answer1.setChecked(false);
cb_answer2.setChecked(false);
cb_answer3.setChecked(false);
cb_answer4.setChecked(false);
cb_answer5.setChecked(false);
cb_answer1.setClickable(true);
cb_answer2.setClickable(true);
cb_answer3.setClickable(true);
cb_answer4.setClickable(true);
cb_answer5.setClickable(true);
}}
```

This works fine but I wanted to shorten this code. So I created an array with the CheckBox-Names (as a class variable) and replaced the above Code with the following for-loop:

```
                    for (CheckBox cb : answerCheckBoxes){
                        cb.setChecked(false);
                        cb.setClickable(true);
                    }
```

Now I'm getting a NullPointerException -> CheckBox.setChecked(boolean) on a null object reference. I don't understand why I'm getting this exception.

What is the problem?

EDIT:
This is my array:

```
CheckBox[] answerCheckBoxes = { cb_answer1, cb_answer2, cb_answer3,   
cb_answer4, cb_answer5 };.
```

If I put this in my onclick-method it works, but as class variable it doesn't work.

Can someone explain me this behavior?

Comment: Stop setting clickable unless you're at some point setting clickable to false. Stop setting checked, checkboxes automatically toggle their state between checked and unchecked.

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the array, and possibly where you are instantiating those checkboxes?

Comment: This is my array: CheckBox[] answerCheckBoxes = { cb_answer1, cb_answer2, cb_answer3, cb_answer4, cb_answer5 };

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that exception because your cb is null. Just change your code to this:

```
for (CheckBox cb : answerCheckBoxes){
    if (cb != null) {
        cb.setChecked(false);
        cb.setClickable(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the original code worked without trowing NPE, it means the checkboxes were initialized, and simply adding the checkboxes to an array and using a loop should not throw NPE either.  In other words, there may be a mistake in creating this array and your null check might be hiding a bug instead of solving anything.